# How to add a dollar sign to this output (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

The following code outputs the prices of some items:

```
var $dishPrice = $("<span>").addClass("dish-price").text(topDish.price || '').appendTo($header);
```

I would like to add a dollar sign right before each number.
What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: What about `.text("$" + topDish.price)` or something like that? Will that be evaluated as a selector eventually?

Comment: Before each number, i.e. 125.45 becomes $125.45 or $1$2$5.$4$5? Bit confused, or maybe the question is just overly simplistic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `'$' +` before your output :

```
var $dishPrice = $("<span>").addClass("dish-price")
.text('$' + topDish.price || '').appendTo($header);
```

In JS, `+` is not only used to add numbers but also concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple currencies, I would say doing it in CSS might be a simpler solution. Reason for that is the fact that some currency are displayed on the left side of the price, while others on the right side.

So simply add the currency type as a class name.

**JavaScript:**

```
var $dishPrice = $("<span>").addClass("dish-price").addClass("usd").text(topDish.price || '').appendTo($header);
```

**CSS:**

```
.dish-price.usd:before{content:'$'}
/* For example Swiss Francs goes to the right side */
.dish-price.chf:after{content:' franc'}
```

Comment: For whoever down-voted, may I ask why? What's bad using this approach?

Comment: i didn't downvote, but i assume it's too much hassle for such a simple problem. Though i agree; please explain your downvote (always!)

Comment: Even though this is a simple problem and the answer is over egging the pudding, I am up voting it as I actually learned some CSS from this :) thanks

Comment: +1 Seems like a much cleaner solution to me than adding $ with Javascript. I'd be interested in the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @giorgio There is "easy" and there is "elegant".

Answer (score 2):

```
var $dishPrice = $("<span>").addClass("dish-price").text('$' + topDish.price || '').appendTo($header);
```

like this?